# "rm: illegal option -- j " when trying to delete a folder that starts with a dash

Tags: bash

```
$>ls
awesome_rails_app
$>rails new --javascript=jquery
**Normally, I would treat --javascript=jquery as a command line 
option...but since you didn't give me a name for your app, I'm assuming 
you actually want me to generate an app named --javascript=jquery. 
Here's your new app!**
$>ls
--javascript=jquery
awesome_rails_app
$>
```

So obviously, I want to be able to delete this app...*but*...

```
$>rm -rf --javascript=jquery
rm: illegal option -- j
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file
$>
```

What should I do now?

Comment: `rm -rf -- --javascript=jquery` is another classic approach.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `./` prefix to the file name so it does not look like an option argument:

```
$>rm -rf ./--javascript=jquery
$>ls
awesome_rails_app
$>
```

I actually found the solution on a blog post at the Electric Toolbox: ["Delete a file starting with a dash/hypen on Linux on the command line"](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/delete-file-starting-with-dash-hyphen/).

Comment: Or use `rm -rf -- --javascript=jquery` (where `--` alone signifies end of options)